FAA to TC conversion
I am trying to convert my FAA ATPL to a Canadian ATPL. However I need to do an IPC and a Bi-annual flight review. Does anyone know of  anywhere/anyone in Canada  that can do this? I need to do it here in Canada.

Does this thread help?
